# Which one is faster: session.createCriteria() or session.createQuery() in hibernate?

Tags: java, performance, hibernate

Is there any difference in performance if we are using hibernate criteria queries
instead of create queries? I looked the web but didn't found a satisfactory answer.

Comment: I've personnaly never seen an appreciable performance gap between the two in my Hibernate profiling. But both pale in comparison to `NamedQuery` because the former need to be compiled internally to produce the final SQL, while the later are parsed once and for all. You'd have to throw `DetachedCriteria` in the mix for a fair comparison. Any way we're talking milliseconds or less, here.

Comment: The cost of generating the SQL query from HQL or criteria is negligible compared to the cost of executing the SQL query. Use what is the most readable. Unless the query is indeed a criteria query (i.e. a query wilth multiple optional criteria that needs to be dynamically composed), HQL is much more readable.

Comment: Try them both. Measure it. If there's no significant difference between (which I suspect there won't be), then pick whichever one gives you easier to read code.

Answer (score 0):

session.createQuery() (**HQL/JPQL queries**) and session.createCriteria() (**Criteria queries**) have the same performance and efficiency.

Criteria queries are more flexible and provide better support for writing dynamic queries as compared to HQL and JPQL. But HQL and JPQL provide native query support that isn't possible with the Criteria queries. This is one of the disadvantages of the Criteria query. We can easily write complex joins using JPQL native queries, whereas it gets difficult to manage while applying the same with Criteria API.

[more info](https://www.baeldung.com/jpql-hql-criteria-query)